# Dynamic query with linq to IDictionary<string, object>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

*This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627867/linq-query-to-return-a-dictionarystring-string) but not quite the same.*

Can I make a dynamic query on a linq-to-sql data context and have the result return as an IDictionary<string, object> where the key is the name of the column?

A bit like so (doesn't compile, but illustrates the intention)

```
IDictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
data = db.ExecuteQuery<IDictionary<string, object>(queryString, params).ToDictionary(
    k=>nameOfColumn,
    k=>k
)
```

Obviously I'm totally off the map in the data = db.ExecuteQuery...
I have the feeling that the executeQuery is not what I'm ought to use as this one already tries to do the mapping to an object. For this particular use case I don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to include an object type to materialize; how about:

```
var data = db.ExecuteQuery<SomeType>(queryString, params)
          .ToDictionary(st => st.SomeKey);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make Linq try to parse the values to the SomeType?

Comment: Yes... but what is the alternative - `object`? If you don't have typed data, then LINQ may not be the best option; just use ADO.NET and SqlCommand.ExecuteReader

Comment: Indeed, I in the meanwhile already did that.
Maybe I should research if I can make my typed data somehow plug in on Linq's parsing.