# LINQ using C# question

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<T>` that contains some user defined class data.

I want to find the unique instances of a combination of 2 data fields.

For example, if the entries contain the fields Name and Age, I want the unique cases of the Name and Age combination, e.g. Darren 32, should only be retrieved once, even if it is in the list multiple times.

Can this be achieved with LINQ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to extract only these data fields and make them unique:

```
var result = list
  .Select(x => new { Age = a.Age, Name = x.Name})
  .Distinct();
```

This creates a IEnumerable of a anonymous type which contains a Age and Name property.

If you need to find the items behind the unique data, you need `GroupBy`. This will provide the list with the single items behind each group.

```
var result = list
  .GroupBy(x => new { Age = a.Age, Name = x.Name});

foreach (var uniqueItem in result )
{
    var age = uniqueItem.Key.Age;
    var name = uniqueItem.Key.Name;
    foreach (var item in uniqueItem)
    {
       //item is a single item which is part of the group
    }
}
```

Comment: Howdy - looks good, but the type's anonymous, not dynamic. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

```
myList.Select(l => new { l.Name, l.Age })
      .Distinct()
      .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Age)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but how do I then store the two values, in say a dictionary?  I get an error saying cannot convert?  Thanks again.

Comment: Use the ToDictionary method, more info in this question, look at first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627867/linq-query-to-return-a-dictionarystring-string

Comment: Dictionary will throw an ArgumentException for Same `Name` and different `Age`

Comment: true, makes no sense to store it in dictionary, I will leave that up to Darren Young to decide; personally I would keep it in the list

Comment: I like `.ToLookup(...)`. It works like `Dictionary<K, IEnumerable<V>>` and stops the issue with duplicate names.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to write your own [equality comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx), and use Linq's [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `Distinct` extension method

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
var people = new List<Person>();

// code to populate people

var uniqueNameAges =
    (from p in people
     select new { p.Name, p.Age }).Distinct();
```

And then to a dictionary:

```
var dictionary =
    uniqueNameAges
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Age);
```

Or to a lookup (very much like `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>>` in this case):

```
var lookup =
    uniqueNameAges
    .ToLookup(x => x.Name, x => x.Age);
```

If you then have people named "John" with distinct ages then you could access them like so:

```
IEnumerable<int> ages = lookup["John"];
```