# idictionary help filtering items

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to code the **Where** this:

```
    IDictionary<string, string> p = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    p.Add("Apple", "1");
    p.Add("Orange", "2");
    p.Add("Pear", "3");
    p.Add("Grape", "4");
    p.Add("Pineapple", "5");
    //This is a unique list

    var retVal = p.Where(k => k.Key.Contains("Apple") || k.Key.Contains("Pear") || k.Key.Contains("Grape"));
```

**Some History Below**

I have a dictionary of strings like the following:

```
IDictionary<string,string>
```

The contents look like this:

```
Apple,1
Orange,2
Pear,3
Grape,4
...many more
```

How do i return only a few items from my dictionary like so

```
if (true)
{
  //return only 3 apple,pear&grape items out of the dozens in the list into a new variable
}
```

Comment: ... that's not filtering, that's 'taking' 3 items.  Or is it?

Comment: What 3 things would you want to return?  There are a ton of ways you can return only 3 items: top 3 based on index order, top 3 based on alphabetic order, random 3, etc.  Also, by "return" do you mean return as results of a method call?

Comment: @squillman - i'd like to take the three items and bind to my dropdownlist in view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just take the first 3 items...

```
theDictionary.Take(3);
```

Or filter and take specific items...

```
string[] itemsIWant = { "Apple", "Pear", "Grape" };

theDictionary.Where(o => itemsIWant.Contains(o.Key));
```

Or sort randomly and take 3...

```
Random r = new Random();

theDictionary.OrderBy(o => r.Next()).Take(3);
```

Comment: please see my 3 specific items (no longer random) sorry for confusion

Comment: @rod: I've updated my answer but they way you'r doing it is already "fine."

Answer (score 0):

check out 
[LINQ query to return a Dictionary<string, string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627867/linq-query-to-return-a-dictionarystring-string)

Comment: And he needs to filter in it? what's the problem : /

Comment: Yes, assuming the OP wants a dictionary back, all of the other answers here all return an IEnumerable; thus, the OP might want to end his `.Take(3)` or `.Where(...)` with a `.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)`.  +1 for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

That will really depend on the kind of filtering you want to achieve. But you can achieve it through Linq.

If you just want to get the first 3 items, you can do it like this:

```
theDictionary.Take(3);
```

If you want to get the first 3 items that begin with 'G', the you will do this:

```
theDictionary.Where(kv => kv.Key.StartsWith("G")).Take(3);
```

If you want to get the first 3 items that begin with 'G' regardless the casing, the you will do this:

```
theDictionary.Where(kv => kv.Key.ToLower().StartsWith("g")).Take(3);
```

Last, but not least, if you want to get 3 items randomly, you will do this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
theDictionary.OrderBy(kv => rand.Next()).Take(3);
```

Comment: This answer is virtually an exact copy of an earlier answer with no additional value or detail.

Comment: @Anthony As an experienced user, you might know that things happen fast in SO. How much time do you think it took me to write my answer? Did you realize that @Josh firstly wrote a very short answer? So I decided to write one with more code and more complete. And then Josh completed his answer as well. How many "different correct answers" do you think there are for filtering a IDictionary?

Comment: In addition, beginners usually do not really know how to handle IDictionary using lambda expressions (Key/Value structure). The code I posted shows that as well.

Comment: @all - please see my 3 specific items (no longer random) sorry for confusion

Comment: @rod You still need to be more specific. Can you have more than one "Apple" in the list?