# how to convert ListItemCollection (dropdownlist.items) to a dictionary<string,string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq, oop

How to convert `ListItemCollection` (`DropDownList.items`) to a `Dictionary<String, String>`(I know it can be done through for each loop) is there any other way linq?

Comment: In addition to the already correct answer: The corresponding MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx (since I've already looked it up)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
collection.Cast<ListItem>().ToDictionary(i => i.Value, i => i.Text);
```

It's not immediately known what the type of the item is, hence the cast method (at least intellisense didn't bring it up for me).  But ToDictionary() should get you there, and specify whatever you want as the key and the value.

HTH.

Answer (score 5):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627867/linq-query-to-return-a-dictionarystring-string):

```
var result = 
  dropdownlist.items.Cast<ListItem>()
                   .ToDictionary(item => item.Value, 
                                 item => item.Text, 
                                 StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```