# ASP Dropdown.FindByText if duplicate ListItem.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, listitem

I've got an ASP DropDownList that I am using the FindByText() method to pull out any matching ListItems.

If there are more than one ListItems with the same Text property (but different Values), what does the method return?

From what I see, it should only return a single ListItem, but then what would happen in this particular case. Does it only return a single result (similar to FirstOrDefault)?

Would it be better to iterate through the DropDownList and for each ListItem, do whatever checks I need to do? Is FindByText even more efficient than a foreach loop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

no need to iterate just use FindAll() like this

```
 List<ListItem> myList;
 var allWhatEver = myList.FindAll(x=>x.Text == "what ever")
```

Comment: okay i see what you are getting at, but what is the best way to actually get that List<ListItem>? I'm starting out with an pre-filled dropdown.

Comment: I think you can use FindAll  on the list you have on the dropdownlist

Comment: hmm I am running through all the available methods for DropDownList.Items ... only found FindByText, FindByValue. This solution would make more sense if it was an actual List.

Comment: ah but I did find this so this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586432/how-to-convert-listitemcollection-dropdownlist-items-to-a-dictionarystring-st thanks anyway!