# Group by Month in a MVC Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a mvc razor view that has a model populated like so:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private IDataSource _db;

        public HomeController (IDataSource db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }


        public ActionResult Events()
        {
            var allevents = _db.Events;
            ViewBag.Title = "Events";
            return View(allevents);
        }


    }
```

The event model looks like this:

```
 public class Event
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location {get;set;}
        public virtual DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
        public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to display the items in my view so that they are grouped by the month name. For example:

**October**

EventA Title, EventA Description etc.

EventB Title, EventA Description etc.

**November**

EventC Title, EventC Description etc.

If possible you could take it a step further to break it out by year, then month however not entirely necessary as I don't see a situation where events would be entered more than a year in advance.

I have tried this in my razor view but seem to be slightly off...

```
@{var monthList = from e in Model
group e by e.StartDate.Month into g
orderby g.Key
select g;

foreach(var monthGroup in monthList)
{

    string month = monthGroup.Key.ToString();
<h2 class="h4 pi-weight-700 pi-uppercase pi-has-bg pi-margin-bottom-25">
    @month
</h2>
    foreach (Model e in monthGroup)
    {
        // do something with the events
    }
}}
```

Comment: This should be done in the controller, is _db.Events IQueryable ? If so do a little bit of LINQ to group them.

Comment: Your `_db` probably returns an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryble` object. Simply call `GroupBy` and then `ToDictionary` on your model. There are a lot of examples here. Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627867/linq-query-to-return-a-dictionarystring-string).

Comment: More to the point, what have you tried?

Comment: If you have Event A: start date- 1st jan, 2014 ; End date- 1st Sep, 2014. Event B: start date- 1st Mar, 2014 ; End date- 1st Aug, 2014. How do you wish to display them?

Comment: Sorry, very new to MVC and LINQ. Updated my question with what I've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming start date and end date are in the same month I would do something like (in controller):

```
var groupedEvents = _db.Events.ToList().GroupBy(k => new DateTime(k.StartDate.Year, k.StartDate.Month, 1)).OrderBy(k => k.Key).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());
return View(groupedEvents);
```

Then in the view foreach through the dictionary. You can get the month name by:

```
@model IDictionary<DateTime, List<Event>>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
     //Display month name
     <h1>@item.Key.ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);</h1>
     foreach(var ev in item.Value)
     {
         //Row specific code
     }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `foreach(var item in **model**`? I'd probably recommend using a different variable than `model` such as `eventsByMonth` etc for the exact confusion that just happened.

Comment: Grouped by month and year as I assumed that you could have events crossing a year boundary. You could also use new MyObject { Year = k.StartDate.Year, Month = k.StartDate.Month } instead of a date-time if you created a MyObject class (haven't used anon types so you can have a strongly typed view model).

Comment: Fair enough, I'll clarify

Comment: getting error:
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Comment: Ah sorry, try now (with the additional ToList() call).