# LINQ to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

Can I build a dictionary directly with LINQ?

I have the following code:

```
    var L = (from C in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().AsParallel()
        where !(C.FullName.Contains("System") || C.FullName.Contains("Microsoft") || C.FullName.Contains("mscorlib"))
        from E in C.GetManifestResourceNames().ToList()
        select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(E, C.FullName)).ToDictionary(_ => _.Key, _ => _.Value);
```

Is it possible to build a dictionary directly instead of generating KeyValuePair objects and then build the dictionary from them?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't need `KeyValuePair` to create dictionary with linq, perhaps an anonymous type to hold keys and values. So yes, it's possible.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627867/linq-query-to-return-a-dictionarystring-string)

Comment: can you point me to an example with the proper syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ query to return a Dictionary<string, string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627867/linq-query-to-return-a-dictionarystring-string)

Comment: @Dido and Camilo, it's not a duplicate as the question you linked to uses the fluent syntax and not the linq one for its solution.

Comment: You cannot execute the LINQ without fluent syntax, only construct it.

Comment: true, but the answer in that post rebuilt everything as fluent while I'm looking for just that one last step to execute it

Comment: It only did so because the query syntax was useless in that post, but it is still a duplicate.

Comment: yes, but in my purpose, I'm practicing using that syntax, so it was quite relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using C# 7.1 or later (VS2017.3+), then you can swap that key/value pair for a tuple:

```
var L = (from C in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().AsParallel()
    where !(C.FullName.Contains("System") || C.FullName.Contains("Microsoft") || C.FullName.Contains("mscorlib"))
    from E in C.GetManifestResourceNames()
    select (E, C.FullName)).ToDictionary(x => x.E, x => x.FullName);
```

Also, I'd recommend avoiding using underscore (`_`) as an identifier name. As of C# 7, it is used as a [discard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/06/27/c-7-series-part-4-discards/) and there is even [talk of deprecating it as an identifier in future versions of the language](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1064).

Comment: Why create tuples when you can just select anonymous types?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Why use an anonymous type when a tuple can be used?

Comment: +1 for the discard. I have *tons* of code using it as a temp variable in situations like above.. time to do some refactoring...

Comment: @Thomas bear in mind that the proposal to deprecate it as an identifier is controversial and may not happen. But once you start using discards, having underscores as identifiers does quickly become confusing, so it’s likely still a worthwhile refactor.

Comment: Yes, I read the thread and wrote that I'd be in favor of it if a good replacement is implemented; others have proposed the @.Data syntax, which I guess would work for me

Answer (score 4):

You can select directly the required data and perform [ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx) on it:

```
var L = (from C in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().AsParallel()
         where !(C.FullName.Contains("System") || C.FullName.Contains("Microsoft") || C.FullName.Contains("mscorlib"))
         from E in C.GetManifestResourceNames()
         select new { E, C.FullName })
    .ToDictionary(elem => elem.E, elem => elem.FullName);
```

Notice that you'll get an `ArgumentException` if there is a duplicate  `ManifestResourceName`.

Comment: select new { K = E, V = C.FullName}).ToDictionary(_ => _.K, _ => _.V); worked. thanks

Comment: @Camilo: Thanks for the link, but but w/o a VS to test my Code I'll prefix "Try" - Code might contain Errors or blurp due to data which I couldn't verify - my internal Compiler is not that great.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: If you can't be sure the code works (which is fair) then I'd advise linking to the documentation to the method you are using - that way if it doesn't work then people can read the documentation to find out how it should work. Though in fact I'd recommend linking to the documentation even if you have tested the code.