# Populate Dictionary in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

How can I combine the population of my `dictionary` inside the LINQ query

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, string> my_dict= new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var query = from blah in blahblahList
                // stuff .. code 
                // some other code
                join meta in metaList on key equals meta.Name
                select new
                {
                    ItemVal = blah[key],
                    ItemType = meta.Type,
                };

    
    foreach (var q in query)
    {
        PopulateMyGlobalDictionary(q.ItemVal, q.ItemType);
    }
```

So I want to not to have to keep the `foreach`. That `PopulateMyGlobalDictionary` is just a simple `method`  **that does a one-liner logic first** and then if `dictionary` doesn't contain this key will add it. That's all. But it has one extra line of logic in it

Comment: Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627867/linq-query-to-return-a-dictionarystring-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953919/convert-linq-query-result-to-dictionary)

Comment: @devlincarnate  sorry, I updated my question to explain the difference.  Basically I kind of either need to keep my PopulateMyGlobalDictionary method or somehow combine its logic inside the LINQ.

Comment: Given your strict requirements, assuming you're working with an existing dictionary, the best you could do is create an extension method and call that. You're not going to get what you want if you want to do this the _proper_ way and not abuse linq.

Comment: @JeffMercado `Aggregate` is part of LINQ :)... (but I'd not recommend going that route for real - only for entertainment/educational purposes)